# Rails 5 api trying to get and show pdf file that is in my Documents folder

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

I have a file in my home/myuser/Documentos/datos/ejemplo.pdf

I wan to to make a controller to show this pdf in my api

```
 def verpdf

    data = open("#{Dir.home}/Documentos/datos/ejemplo.pfd") 
    send_data data.read, filename: "ejemplo.pdf", type: "application/pdf", disposition: 'inline', stream: 'true', buffer_size: '4096' 
end
```

this is my url localhost:3000/verpdf and when I go to this url it opens a dialog box asking where i want to save the file. But i only need the file to be showed because it is an api that serve files to an Android app, is that the correct way? I need when the user press link in the Android app (localhost:3000/verpdf) the pdf opens. Is that the rigth way? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how dynamic will be files, you can only give url to let open a file.

```
def verpdf
    url = "#{Dir.home}/Documentos/datos/ejemplo.pdf"
    render json: {date: url}, status: :ok
end
```